# C++ stopping function that doesn't return anything

Tags: c++

I have a program in C++ which checks if a port is open or close of a given IP. What I intent to do is to check in which ip's of a network are some device.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <string>

static bool port_is_open(const std::string& address, int port)
{
    return (sf::TcpSocket().connect(address, port) == sf::Socket::Done);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Port 80 : ";


    if (port_is_open("localhost", 80))
        std::cout << "OPEN" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "CLOSED" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is when I check some IP that doesn't has any device on it the function port_is_open stuck the program. Who can I stop ths function if in a certain time doesn't get response?

Comment: That would depend on your SFML library. Look through their documentation for some form of timeout for connect()

Answer (score 4):

Here is `connect()` declaration:

```
Status connect (const IpAddress &remoteAddress, unsigned short remotePort, Time timeout=Time::Zero)
```

Just supply third argument and it *should* stop connecting itself.

Comment: I've tryed but it gives me an error. Instead I've done this but the function is not ending..

    static bool port_is_open(const std::string& address, int port)
    {
       
        sf::Time timeout = sf::Time::Zero;
        
        return (sf::TcpSocket().connect(address, port, timeout) == sf::Socket::Done);
        
    }